# How to find out if any Dll is part of .NET Framework 4.8?

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

There are many NuGet packages starting with `System.` or `Microsoft.` prefixes. Some of these are genuinely part of the .Net Framework, but many are *NOT*.

I am looking for a quick and reliable way to check whether `some.dll` in version x.y obtained from NuGet is part of the .NET Framework (specifially: 4.8) or not, so I know whether to include that .dll file with my deployment. With .Net Standard, .NET Core, and .NET, along with many packages with transitive dependencies, things get complicated quickly.

How can I do this?

**New assumptions and questions**

As far as I understand the feedback from Panagiotis Kanavos and JonasH, there should not be any reason to worry about my original question.
All files that are needed at customers side are copied to the build output. All nuget.org packages are not part of .NET Framework 4.8 and should therefore be shipped to customers.

Mentioned by JonasH, I can use "Right click the project references, select add, and assemblies." to get a list .NET Framework 4.8 assemblies. Another great suggestion is the new SDK-style format of .csproj files showing detailed dependencies graphs.

Here are some new questions/irregularities we don't understand when working with transitive dependencies (e.g. Refit):

1. Why are there nuget.org Packages available .NET Framework 4.8, that do not contain any file for .NET Framework 4.8?
   Example: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks
   According nuget.org, it is compatible to .NET Framework 4.5.

Are those packages added as dependency, because they could be used in .NET Core/.NET Standard libraries where they´re required? Since they do not contain any file for .NET Framework, it doesn't make sense to use them .NET Framework projects, does it?

2. Why is `System.Net.Http` found in Visual Studio as .NET Framework 4.8 assembly, but also as nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http ?
   Is it because the version on nuget.org is newer/higher with more features?

If yes, why is there no `System.Net.Http.dll` copied to our build output if we create a new empty project and add `System.Net.Http 4.3.4`  as dependency. Or as in our case, add a dependency to `Refit 7.0.0` having a transitive dependency to `System.Net.Http 4.3.4`. We would expect a new version of `System.Net.Http.dll` in our build folder. According to https://nuget.info/packages/System.Net.Http/4.3.4 there should be a .dll for net46.

Comment: Why do you care about this? .NET itself uses the correct type already. The 4.8 version of a .NET Standard package will use the available 4.8 runtime type if it runs on a 4.8 runtime, otherwise it will use the updated version. All this is transparent to both the application and the developer

Comment: Because our builds have many `System.*` files and we would like to double check if these files are really needed on customers side. I would not ask the question if it would be transparent to me personally.

Comment: That doesn't explain much. When you publish a project all the necessary DLLs are copied to the `publish` project. On the production machine, calls will be redirected to the runtime if the versions match or the libraries if they don't.

Comment: Are you trying to reduce the deployment size? Or did you try to deploy an application and encountered an error?

Comment: We found `System.IO.Compression.dll`, `System.IO.Log.dll`, `System.Net.Http.dll` inside our builds among others. As far as I know these are part of .NET Framework and should not be shipped? It is tough to know which is which just by the files and our builds are a mess sometimes.

Comment: Unless they're newer versions than the installed runtime in which case they're needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have updated my question. I would be very happy to receive feedback from again.